# Cannot connect to Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I hope you can help, I’ve been stucked in this issue for months.

I have deployed an Azure VM, I have NSG properly set up with RDC ports. But the issue is that I cannnot comnectfrom some networks. I also have some sites deployed in that vm iis. Please refer below description.

RDC 
A friend (A) of mine Local Network: works
A friend (B) of mine Local Network: doesn’t work 
Local Network: doesn’t work
My cellphone data: works

HTTP website
A friend (A) of mine Local Network: works
A friend (B) of mine Local Network: Works
Local Network: works
My cellphone data: works

HTTPS website
A friend (A) of mine Local Network: works
A friend (B) of mine Local Network: doesn’t work
Local networks: doesn’t work
My cellphone data: works

Hope someone can help... thanks

Comment: The site is intended for programming questions so this will likely be flagged as off topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can always start with the RDP Troubleshooting doc we have:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-rdp-connection

Besides that, it sounds like a local network issue. If you can connect from one network but not another there could be a firewall in place blocking you from connecting. We have seen this often on company corp nets. And as per the NSG comment you made, for testing purposing Try allowing RDP connections from any IP address. Then you can modify it to only specific IPs as needed. Overall though I would say a local firewall issue.